# Codificacion de caracteres sql php

Tags: php, sql

Hola a todos les pido ayuda ya que estoy haciendo una página en php y sql, y tengo una clase la cual crea una conexión a una base de datos y quiero hacer que por cada vez que se cree va a ejecutar la siguiente consulta:

```
$db->query('SET NAMES utf8');
```

La variable $db es el objeto de la conexión, hasta ahí todo va bien ya que esa consulta si se genera bien incluso si lo hago en consola, lo malo es que si guardo un registro con un acento o algo asi lo guarda de esta forma:

```
&eacute;
```

Todo eso es solo para representar un acento en la e, por lo que enconces creo que no esta codificando los caracteres correctamente, ¿alguien me puede decir como puedo hacer que acepta los caracteres de forma correcta? Quiero aclarar que esto lo hacía asi antes y funcionaba bien, ¿tiene algo que ver el sistema operativo o algo asi? Desde ya gracias a todos :)

Comment: ¿Cómo guardas el contenido? Probablemente estás usando algún editor de texto enriquecido como CKEditor o similar, que es el que aplica esos cambios y deberías revertirlos antes de guardar en base de datos.

Comment: El problema aquí es que por algún motivo no estás obteniendo caracteres, sino sus correspondientes **entidades HTML**. Entonces, debes verificar por qué ocurre eso en tu código. ¿Vienen los datos así? Entonces conviértelos usando [**`html_entity_decode()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.html-entity-decode.php) o de otro modo o modifica en el origen para que no mande los datos como entidades HTML. ¿Son convertidos *in situ* en tu código? Pues evita que sean convertidos. En cuanto a la BD, si usas PDO debes saber que puedes indicar el charset en el DSN de la conexión.

Comment: @A.Cedano gracias, con la funcion que dejaste ya funciono  y  ya recibe los caracteres correctamente

Comment: @Triby uso vs code, pero A. Cenado ya me ayuda con la pregunta, de todos modos gracias

Comment: Me alegro. De todos modos deberías revisar por qué los datos están llegando como entidades y si es posible corregir en el origen. Mientras menos manipulaciones y conversiones haya a medio camino es mejor, sin poner en riesgo la **seguridad**. Incluso, puede que eso ocurra debido a filtros que son aplicados en el mismo código en que haces la inserción. A veces se abusa de los filtros. Si esos datos son sólo para insertar en la BD (no para mostrar en pantalla), no deberían ser filtrados... y **usar consultas preparadas ESO SÍ**, es la única seguridad a aplicar en ese caso. Saludos.

Comment: @A.Cedano gracias, voy a tomar en cuenta lo que dijiste y revisar como puedo hacer menos manipulaciones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema aquí es que por algún motivo no estás obteniendo caracteres, sino sus correspondientes [entidades HTML](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref).

Entonces, debes verificar por qué ocurre eso en tu código.

¿Vienen los datos así? Entonces conviértelos usando [`html_entity_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.html-entity-decode.php) o de otro modo o modifica en el origen para que no mande los datos como entidades HTML (a no ser que convenga por motivos de seguridad).

¿Son convertidos *in situ* en tu código? Pues evita que sean convertidos (a no ser que dichos datos deban también ser mostrados en pantalla, en cuyo caso es más seguro aplicarles filtros para tales fines).

Sea como sea, considera aplicar sólo los filtros que sean necesarios según el uso que vayas a darle a los datos. Y, para insertarlos en la base de datos usa siempre consultas preparadas, pues son el método más seguro para evitar ataques de *Inyección SQL*.

En cuanto a la BD, si usas PDO debes saber que puedes indicar el charset en el DSN de la conexión ([ver **Ejemplo 3** en el Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqlinfo.concepts.charset.php)).